# Estimation for dimension of support and associated primes of a module of depth zero

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, modules

Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a local Noetherian ring and $M$ a finitely generated $R$-module of depth zero, ie $\operatorname{depth}(M):=\text{depth}_{\mathfrak{m}}(M)=0$.

Can we make some interesting *upper bound* estimations for

$$\dim \operatorname{Supp}(M)= \dim V(\operatorname{Ann}(M))$$

and $\dim(R/\mathfrak{p})$ for $\mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Ass}(M)$ (finer then the boring one by $\dim R$ :) In addition, is the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ always associated prime to $M$?

Motivation: There are in this setting well known (see [00LK](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00LK) and [0BK4](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BK4)) estimations
**(1)** $\dim (\operatorname{Supp}(M)) \geq \operatorname{depth}(M)$ and **(2)** $\dim (R/\mathfrak p) \geq \operatorname{depth}(M)$ for  $\mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Ass}(M)$. Clearly one can construct examples where these are proper inequalities. Nevertheless it seems interesting to know if the assumption $\operatorname{depth}(M)=0$ - ie that every $r \in \mathfrak{m}$ kills certain element of $M$ - hides some upper extimations for support of $M$ and dimensions of $\dim(R/\mathfrak{p})$ where $\mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Ass}(M)$.

Comment: Let $k$ be the residue field $R/\mathfrak{m}$. Let $N$ be ANY finitely generated non-zero module. Then depth of $M=N\oplus k$ is zero, while $\dim M=\dim N$. So what exactly are you expecting?